# Show one specific country map in MapKit in iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit

Is there any possibility of **show a specific country map in iOS** using Swift?

I have already search a lot, but most other answers are suggesting to bound map with a zooming effect only.

But I think this is not the correct solution for me.

Answer (score 5):

beware the following coordinates are random just as example.

somewhere in your swift code you will have declared your `MKMapView`

`@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!`

and later on, possibly in `override func viewDidLoad()`, 
you can set the `region` of your mapview and the `span`.

```
var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
var region: MKCoordinateRegion!
var span: MKCoordinateSpan!

mapView = MKMapView() // allocating a mapview, so setting the region makes sens.

location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(2.0, 1.0)
span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, span: span)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

And remember maps don't come with a list of countrys and borders to choose from, but there are services that help you to find location coordinates by address or country names.

one of the methods to find a map region by country name..
sorry, in objective-c..

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    MKPlacemark *placemark = nil;
    MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] initWithNaturalLanguageQuery:@"USA"];
    request.resultTypes = MKLocalSearchResultTypeAddress;
    MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self.mapView setRegion:response.boundingRegion];
            
            //or do something with first result..
            //if ([response mapItems].count>0) {
                // MKPlacemark *placemark = [response mapItems].firstObject.placemark;
                // MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
                // and so on..
            //}
        }
    }];
}
```

or swift

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    
    let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "USA"
    
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
    
    search.start { response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error").")
            return
        }
        
        self.mapView.setRegion(response.boundingRegion, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are curious how to place overlay as country border from a plist [here an example in github](https://github.com/nagam11/Countries-borders). Or you go on with a service that has the needed data of land cover by country like [discussed in stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177741/seeking-free-shapefile-of-european-countries/286740)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any possibility to show a specific country map in iOS

<del>Regardless of the programming language, that is only possible if your app has associated data (center and region) for each country you want to display. MapKit itself has no such feature.</del>

This is in fact possible as @OlSen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64434916/1918561) shows.

Comment: not 100% true.. sorry. .https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/converting_a_user_s_location_to_a_descriptive_placemark?language=objc

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and your example code! I wasn't aware local searches worked for this as well, good to know! Your answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most of the answers, in that MapKit doesn't support this out of the box.

If you haven't already take a look at the [Apple Docs for MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit) to understand better how you can utilise your own data, in a simple way.

However you are free to annoate MapKit with your own custon shapes, which conform to the MKOverlay protocol.

> see [MKOverlayRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkoverlayrenderer)